# stack different dataframes in a function

Tags: r, dplyr, stack, tidyverse, plyr

I am having troubles to stack a variable number of data-frames whithin a for-loop. Can someone please help me?

```r
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(here)
```

A function that should open all excel-files and create one single file using `plyr::rbind.fill()`:

```r
stackDfs <- function(filenames){
  for(fn in filenames){
    df1 <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(here::here("folder1", "folder2", fn), sheet=6, detectDates = TRUE)
    # ... do some additional mutations here
  }
    
  all_dfs <- (plyr::rbind.fill(df1, df2, df3, df4, ...)
  return(all_dfs)
}
```

Here I am defining which files should be opened and call the stacking-function. The number of files to be stacked should be variable.

```r
filenames <- c("filexy-20210202.xlsx", "filexy-2021-20210205.xlsx")
stackDfs(filenames)
```

Comment: Already you have a solution. But had you tried purrr::map or dplyr::bind_rows?
`purrr::map_dfr(filenames, ~openxlsx::read.xlsx(here::here("folder1", "folder2", .x), sheet=6, detectDates = TRUE))` You don't need a for loop and a new function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current setup, we can initialize a `list`, read the data into the `list` and then apply `rbind.fill` within `do.call`

```
stackDfs <- function(filenames){
    out_lst <- vector('list', length(filenames))
    names(out_list) <- filenames
    for(fn in filenames){
     out_list[[fn]] <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(here::here("folder1",
          "folder2", fn), sheet=6, detectDates = TRUE)
      #....
     }
   all_dfs <- do.call(plyr::rbind.fill, out_lst)
   all_dfs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In line with the comment posted about using purrr, if you put all the files in the same folder you can use a package called fs instead of manually entering all the file names:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(here)
library(fs)

filenames <- fs::dir_ls(here("files"))

all_dfs <- filenames %>%
   map_dfr(openxlsx:read.xlsx, sheet = 6, detectDates = TRUE)
all_dfs
```